# Ajax- redirect when success

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to make a validation for login form. What I am doing is to check in database for username and password and if that user doesn't exists to show a message, if it exists redirect to index.php. I have done this using Ajax but the problem is that it shows me the message of failure, but when try to login as an existing user it shows this error at inspect element

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'append' of null jquery-1.9.1.js:7985` and 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined jquery.validate.js:332`

**script.js** :

```
 $('#login_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var username = $('#login_form input[name=username]').val();
        var password = $('#login_form input[name=password]').val();

        $.ajax({
          url: "login.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {username: username,
                password: password},
          success: function(response) {
                 $('#invalid_content').html(response);  
                }
        });

        });
```

**login_form.php**

```
<form id="login_form" action="login.php" method="post">
        <div id="invalid_content" style="color: red"></div><br>
        <div class="control-group">
        <input autofocus id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>          
           </div><br>
        <div class="control-group">
        <input id ="password" name="password" placeholder="Fjalekalimi" type="password"/>
        </div><br>
        <div class="control-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Log In</button>
         </div>
        <br>                    
</form>
```

**login.php**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {      
        $rows = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", $_POST["username"]);

        if (count($rows) == 1)
        {
            $row = $rows[0];                            

            if (crypt($_POST["password"], $row["hash"]) == $row["hash"])
            {
                $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];                       
                echo json_encode(array('msg'=>"Success.", 'url'=>"/kinema/html/index.php", 'status'=>true));
            }


        }
        else if (($_POST["password"], $_POST["username"]) == null){
          echo json_encode(array('msg'=>"Username ose fjalekalimi jane te pavlefshem.", 'url'=>"", 'status'=>false));
        }
    }
    else
    {               
        echo json_encode(array('msg'=>"Username ose fjalekalimi jane te pavlefshem.", 'url'=>"", 'status'=>false));
    }
```

The respone form console is:

```
<br />

    <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
    <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\wamp\www\kinema\html\login.php on line <i>23</i></th></tr>
    </table></font>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You can't able to redirect from inside the ajax page, instead you can follow the below,

```
       $('#login_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var username = $('#login_form input[name=username]').val();
        var password = $('#login_form input[name=password]').val();

        $.ajax({
          url: "login.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {username: username,
                password: password},
          dataType: 'json', // added json datatype
          success: function(response) {
                   if(response.status){ // if status is true then navigate into another page
                     window.location = response.url;
                   }else{ // if the status is false then render the error. 
                       $('#invalid_content').html(response.msg);  

                    }
                }
        });

    });
```

**login .php:**

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
        {      
            $rows = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", $_POST["username"]);
            if (count($rows) == 1)
            {
                $row = $rows[0];
                if (crypt($_POST["password"], $row["hash"]) == $row["hash"])
                {
                    $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];                       
                    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>"Success.", 'url'=>"/kinema/html/index.php", 'status'=>true));
                }
            }elseif (( ( !isset($_POST["password"]) && !isset($_POST["username"]) ) && trim($_POST["password"])=="" && trim($_POST["username"])=="") ) {
                    echo json_encode(array('msg'=>"Username and password are Empty", 'url'=>"", 'status'=>false));
            }else{
                  echo json_encode(array('msg'=>"OOps, there is some other issues!!", 'url'=>"", 'status'=>false));
              }
        }
        else
        {               
            echo json_encode(array('msg'=>"Username ose fjalekalimi jane te pavlefshem.", 'url'=>"", 'status'=>false));
        }


       ?>
```

Comment: it still doesnt't do anything. When i type a valid name and password it doesnt perform any action

Comment: In mozila firefox browser, install the addon called `firebug` developer tool, once you have installed, enable the net panel in firebug and view the response, if the values are posted properly.

Comment: POST login.php 200 OK
 
localhost
 
153 B
 
[::1]:80

Comment: and parameters are ok, response:{"msg":"Success.","url":"http:\/\/localhost\/kinema\/html\/","status":true}{"msg":"Username ose fjalekalimi jane te pavlefshem.","url":"","status":false}

Comment: Got it, Added another else conition in login.php, Updated my answer, please check

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again, but I am trying to add other conditions and once i add one, it doesn't work. I have edited my code please take a look

Comment: Which condition you have added, what is the use of it ?

Comment: in case username and password is empty, because with your code when username and password were empty the user could be logged in. I dont know why just general else case didn't work

Comment: Can you add this `elseif (( ( !isset($_POST["password"]) &&  !isset($_POST["username"]) ) && trim($_POST["password"])=="" &&  trim($_POST["username"])=="") ) {`

Comment: I added it and the same, it's logging in anyway. And at console there is 0 request

Comment: in this case, it doesn't shows the message when username and password are different from existing one. ande the response from console is: <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-parse-error' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in C:\wamp\www\kinema\html\login.php on line <i>23</i></th></tr>
</table></font>

Comment: May be the error missed to close `{` or `)` in somewhere else.